# ELMAH in asp.net mvc2

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, elmah

Can any body give me code to impement ELMAH error handling for my asp.net mvc application..

I need to know step by step process to implemnt?

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have used elmah with asp.net mvc 2.0.You would need to download the source from [here](http://code.google.com/p/elmah/), add the dll to your project and then change your web config to get elmah working it is explained well [here](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ELMAHErrorLoggingModulesAndHandlersForASPNETAndMVCToo.aspx). Also have a look at a similiar [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2118248/asp-net-mvc-elmah-not-working-and-returning-404-page-for-elmah-axd) to get more information or if you run into problems.

Comment: Ok thanks.. if I am goign with ELMAH.. do I need to do Enterprise Library Configuration?
My questions ELMAH or ELC? is the best option?

thanks

Comment: refer this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/940888/elmah-vs-enterprise-library-exception-handling-block

Answer (score 0):

Check out my blog series on logging in MVC. The first article covers getting Elmah set up and running for MVC and expands on what Hanselman does.

There is a link to downloadable code at the end of the article. Hope that helps.

http://dotnetdarren.wordpress.com/