# Microsoft Enterprise Library Opinions

Tags: asp.net, caching, logging, exception, enterprise-library

Has any one used Microsoft's Enterprise Library, if so what parts of it did you use?

I am using building a website (I guess the client app type is not important, it can be a Windows app as well) with all the architectural layer, and I am specifically interested in the `exception handling`, `logging` and `caching` blocks for now.  Any one used these, what were the good and bads of your experience with, any alternatives that you rather decided to use?  Performance is a thing that I am also interested in.

I am looking for a decent exception handling framework which is how I came across the exception handling block.  Anything other out there?

Is it a wise idea to use the data access block with an MVC application seeing that everybody is the repository pattern with an ORM framework?

I am still researching frameworks, so I would like to hear as many opinions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Exception Handling we initially used ELMAH and Log4NET.. but later shifted to Enterprise Library as the client wished to use a more robust and enterprise ready solution. By no means I am saying that ELMAH or Log4NET is not enterprise ready however EntLib does gives you more power. You can read another post here for more details:
[ELMAH vs Enterprise Library Exception Handling Block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/940888/elmah-vs-enterprise-library-exception-handling-block)

Is it a wise idea to use the data access block with an MVC application seeing that everybody is the repository pattern with an ORM framework? 
 - I would not recommend using DAB if you are using repository pattern with an ORM framework.. Especially with EntityFramework the whole point of having a DAB goes for toss.

For Caching - I would recommend using Caching app block to start with and check if Velocity comes in by the time you plan to deploy...

Comment: Thanks. Do you use Velocity? I wat to use an exception handling framework that work across layers as well, so Elmah won't work for me. I was just curious about DAAB.

Comment: Is Velocity free?  You got a link for me?

Comment: @Brendan: Velocity is a free application cache from Microsoft.  It has been renamed as Windows Server AppFabric Caching Services.  See [Developer Introduction to Windows Server AppFabric (Part 2): Caching Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windowsserver/gg675186) for more information.

Comment: I used Velocity in one of the applications and the results were good (I found it less configuration and more rapid to setup as opposed to EntLib CAB)